# Use entered text from view in other view in Swift (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, uitextfield, label

I am almost completely new to Swift and Xcode so excuse my lack of knowledge in this field.
At the moment I have a view controller with a label in it. I want to add a view before that, with a text field in which a user enters a name, the app then goes to the second view with the label in which the name entered by the user is placed on the label.

I know this is very basic, but I cannot find any good solutions since I'm not quite sure what to search for. If anyone has a piece of code or a link to a good source, I'd love to see it.

Thanks!

Edit: I really know little about this. Do I need a navigation controller when using two views? Do I need two ViewController.swift files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it in 12 easy steps:

1) Yes.  I recommend using a `Navigation Controller`.  Start a new project with a *Single View Application*.

2) Select the `ViewController` in the Storyboard and from the Menu bar above select `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller`.

3) Drag out a `UIButton` and a `UITextField` and put them in your first `ViewController`.

4) You'll want an `IBOutlet` to your text field so that you can read the text from it.  *Show the Assistant editor* by clicking on the *Tuxedo* icon in the upper right corner of *Xcode*.  Click on the `ViewController` in the Storyboard.  The right editor pane will show the code for `ViewController`.  Hold down the *Control* key and drag from the text field to the code in the right pane.  Let go on the mouse button when you are in the space just below `class ViewController : UIViewController {`.  In the popup, set *Connection* to *Outlet*, set the name to `textField` and press *Connect*.  This will add the line `@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!` to your `ViewController`.

5) Now it is time to add a second view controller.  From the menu select `File->New->File...`.  In the dialog, make sure *Source* under *iOS* is selected on the left, and choose *Cocoa Touch Class* and press *Next*.  Name the class `SecondViewController` and make it a subclass of `UIViewController`.  Press *Next* and then *Create*.

6) In the Storyboard, drag out a `UIViewController` and drop it to the right of the first `ViewController`.  Select the new `ViewController` and open the *Identity Inspector* by clicking on the 3rd icon from the left in the row of icons below the *Tuxedo* icon.  (Hint: if you hover of the icons it will tell you what they do).  Change the class to `SecondViewController`.

7) In the Storyboard, control-drag (hold down control and drag) from the button in the first `ViewController` to the new `SecondViewController`.  In the pop-up select *Show* as the *Action Segue*.

8) Drag a *Label* out and put it into the `SecondViewController`.  Add an `IBOutlet` to it like you did in step 4 and call it *mylabel*.

9) In the code for `SecondViewController` add a new instance variable like so:  `var firstVCtext = ""`

10) In the first `ViewController` add this method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    secondVC.firstVCtext = textField.text
}
```

11) In `SecondViewController`, add this line of code to the `viewDidLoad` method: `mylabel.text = firstVCtext`

12) Run the program!

Comment: There is a lot of detail here.  If some step gives you trouble, let me know and I can elaborate or add pictures.

Comment: I am very sorry to reply after such a long time. Thank you very much for your elaborate answer, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain it so well. I followed the steps and it works, moreover I understand how it works now better. Again: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another good tutorial here with code and images:

http://www.jamesrambles.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

Answer (score 0):

To move data from one view to another, use of a segue (pronounced seg-way) is the easiest.  One example is here:

http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/

If you Google for Swift and Segue you will likely find more examples.