# Sending data with Segue with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have two view controllers and two views.
In my first view, I set the variable 'currentUser' to false.
I need to be able to set 'currentUser' to true in the second view controller.

When trying to reference 'currentUser' from the second view it's not picking it up as 'currentUser' is defined in the first view controller.

How do I carry across variables with segue?

Answer (score 59):

**Set values from Any ViewController to a Second One using segues**

**Like this:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        let yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
        yourNextViewController.value = yourValue
```

And in your yourNextViewController class.

```
class yourNextViewControllerClass {

    var value:Int! // or whatever
```

You can call this also programmatically:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifierInStoryboard", sender: self)
```

**Set values from your DestinationViewController back to your Primary (First) ViewController**

**1.** Implement a protocol, for example create a file called protocol.swift.

```
    protocol changeUserValueDelegate {
       func changeUser(toValue:Bool)
    }
```

**2.** set the delegate on your second View

```
    class yourNextViewControllerClass {

    var delegate:changeUserValueDelegate?
```

**3.** set the delegate on load (prepareForSegue)

```
    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        var yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
        yourNextViewController.delegate = self
```

**4.** add Function to FirstViewController

```
    func changeUser(toValue:Bool) {
        self.currentUserValue = toValue
    }
```

**5.** call this function from your SecondViewController

```
     delegate?.changeUser(true)
```

**6.** Set the delegate in your FirstViewController

```
    class FirstViewController: UIViewController, ChangeUserValueDelegate {
```

Comment: I can't use function to my knowledge I need to do this within an 'if' statement. Sorry for not making it clearer.

Comment: With this 2 methods you are able to send data from your first to second View Controller, and from your second back to the first one. It should not be a problem to call this in an "if" statement.

Comment: I tried the first method, I could not use the override function in the if statement, the variable is not found in the second view controller.

Comment: Very nice solution.  I searched quite a bit for a way to reach back to the firstViewController before I found this.  A side benefit is that I have now written and used my first home grown protocol!

Comment: A revelation brought about in understanding this variant of inter-controller protocol communication, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The problem here is that your `currentUser` variable is of type `Bool`, which is a value type. So passing it from your first view controller to your second view controller will in fact create a new `Bool` instance. What you need is to pass a reference from your first view controller to your second view controller (see [Value and Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) for more details on value and reference with Swift).

Thereby, according to your needs/preferences, you may choose one of the **three** following examples.

---

## 1. The boxing style

Here, we "box" our `Bool` inside a class and pass a reference of that class instance to the second view controller.

**1.1. Create a `CurrentUser` class:**

```
class CurrentUser {
    var someBooleanValue = true {
        didSet {
            print(someBooleanValue)
        }
    }
}
```

**1.2. Create a `UIViewController` subclass for the first view controller:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    let currentUser = CurrentUser()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentUser.someBooleanValue = false
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let viewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 {
            viewController2.currentUser = currentUser
        }
    }

}
```

**1.3. Create a `UIViewController` subclass for the second view controller:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var currentUser: CurrentUser?

    // Link this IBAction to a UIButton or a UIBarButtonItem in the Storyboard
    @IBAction func toggleBoolean(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let currentUser = currentUser {
          currentUser.someBooleanValue = !currentUser.someBooleanValue
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

## 2. The closure style

Here, we get a weak reference of our first view controller in a closure and pass this closure to the second view controller.

**2.1. Create a `UIViewController` subclass for the first view controller:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    
    var currentUser = true {
        didSet {
            print(currentUser)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentUser = false
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let viewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 {
            let closureToPerform = { [weak self] in
                if let strongSelf = self {
                    strongSelf.currentUser = !strongSelf.currentUser
                }
            }
            viewController2.closureToPerform = closureToPerform
        }
    }
    
}
```

**2.2. Create a `UIViewController` subclass for the second view controller:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var closureToPerform: (() -> Void)?

    // Link this IBAction to a UIButton or a UIBarButtonItem in the Storyboard
    @IBAction func toggleBoolean(sender: AnyObject) {
        closureToPerform?()
    }
    
}
```

---

## 3. The protocol-delegate style

Here, we make our first view controller conform to some protocol and pass a weak reference of it to the second view controller.

**3.1. Create a custom protocol:**

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func changeValue()
}
```

**3.2. Create a `UIViewController` subclass for the first view controller and make it conform to the previous protocol:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController, MyDelegate {

    var currentUser = true {
        didSet {
            print(currentUser)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentUser = false
    }
    
    func changeValue() {
        currentUser = !currentUser
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let viewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 {
            viewController2.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

**3.3. Create a `UIViewController` subclass for the second view controller:**

```
import UIKit
    
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?

    // Link this IBAction to a UIButton or a UIBarButtonItem in the Storyboard
    @IBAction func toggleBoolean(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.changeValue()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute `currentUserSecondVC` in the destination view controller, and use `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Name Of Your Segue" {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as NameOfTheSecondViewController
        vc.currentUserSecondVC = !currentUser //you can do whatever you want with it in the 2nd VC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that should be defined as override is:

```
open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Segue Name Defined In Storyboard") {
        //set the property of the designated view controller with the value you need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using same variable across the two Viewcontrollers, namely currentUser (type Bool).

So its better to make it a global variable in both classes.

**When coming to global variable concept in swift.**

Everything by default in swift is public, and thus if you declare something like this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var someVariable: Boll = YES

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}
```

You can access it and set values as long as you have an instance of it:

```
var MySecondViewController: FirstViewController = FirstViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
var getThatValue = MySecondViewController.someVariable
```