# How I can display another (change) ViewController when I press a button

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, viewcontroller

in my xcode storyboard I have the standard viewController in which I have placed one Button with a Action Outlet.

I tried with an .xib which doesn't load. Further, I tried with an second ViewController in the Storyboard and a custom segue, but this also failed.

There is something I did wrong. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: A screenshot of storyboard with some codes, maybe?

Comment: Storyboard: http://i61.tinypic.com/rqwxs4.png and Code: http://i58.tinypic.com/bejac6.png

Comment: Why didn't you simply put the code and the screenshot in your question? Also, there are errors in your code. And you try to load a storyboard which doesn't seem to exist in the project.

Comment: Raptor want a screenshot ;) 

Now, I created a new cocoa class with .xib file. In my ViewController.swift I created a function with these code:

NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("loginVC", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)

and this function I called in the Button Action. The .xib is loading for now but backwards, form .xib to ViewController, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Segues, you dont need to create a ViewController and try to display it this way. Just give a (unqiue) name to your ViewController (for Example if you dont want to use a "NavigationController" you should use "Modal" as Type. You should add a ViewController Class for each ViewController in Storyboard too.

So connect ViewController1 with your second View Controller and give them a name "loginModal".

Then in your IBAction, you can use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginModal", sender: self)
```

That should be all. If you want to send data between ViewControllers, you should use prepareForSegue. Check out my answer here, youll find more information about sending data with segues.

[Sending data with Segue with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089152/sending-data-with-segue-with-swift/26089243#26089243)

Comment: thank you for this, but I need a Solution for OS X not for iOS. I won't a new Window, I will update the content in the same Window

Comment: Oh i am sorry - only checked the "swift" tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this one

Put this code inside `@IBAction` button.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let loginViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as loginViewController
        self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Don't forget to set identifier's name in loginViewController.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but in OS X you don't have an UIStoryboard, there is nothing with UI like in iOS. Something else?