# Make a public var without making its class and related functions public?

Tags: xcode, swift, scope, global-variables, viewcontroller

I'm starting to learn Swift.

I've a viewController that has a var which needs updating from an outside viewController. So I added public to its declaration but my code won't compile because my class is internal (by default). So i make my class public but then it forces me to make all functions inside my class public including viewDidLoad, the tableView dataSource and delegate methods. What am i doing wrong? I don't want anyone else to call my controller's viewDidLoad.

All I wanted to viewControllerA to access a var inside viewControllerB without exposing every function inside viewControllerB to the outside world.

In ObjC, this can be achieved very easily by marking the property readonly in the headerfile and readwrite in the implementation. In this case, I would've the property in the header file so it's read-writable from outside.

here's some pseudo code

```
    class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
      var myTitle: NSString?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

// objC part

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
myViewController.myTitle = @""; // not available
```

Now if i make myTitle a public var, i get this error

> Declaring a public var for an internal class

So I make MyViewController a public class.

Now i get bunch of errors

> Method 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' must be declared public
>   because it matches a requirement in public protocol
>   'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: ViewControllers are intended to not have knowledge of each-other, a work around is to declare your variable globally. (above your class declaration).

Answer (score 2):

You could make a protocol to save and access data across view controllers. Here's one way to do it.

```
// Make a custom protocol delegate with a method to store the variable. In this case I'll store a boolean.
protocol storeViewControllerBVariableDelegate {
    func storeVariable(data: Bool?)
}

// In your view controller A, assign your custom protocol delegate to it and add the new delegate method.
class viewControllerA: UIViewController, storeViewControllerBVariableDelegate {

    func storeVariable(data: Bool?) {
        self.variableName = data
    }

}

// In your view controller A's prepare for segue, assign the stored variable to view controller B if you wanted to pass it forward and backward between view controllers.
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let viewControllerB = segue.destinationViewController as! viewControllerB

    viewControllerB.variableName = variableName
}

// In your view controller B, initialize a variable and assign it to the delegate.
class viewControllerB: UIViewController {

    var variableName: Bool!
    var delegate: storeViewControllerBVariableDelegate?

    // However you want to save the variable in view controller B, you can do so in an IBAction, viewDidLoad, etc.
    @IBAction func saveVariable(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.storeVariable(self.variableName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions that I can think of for passing variables between view controllers

### Global Option

**ViewController2.swift**

```
import UIKit

var globalVariable = String()

class ViewController1: UIViewConroller {


}
```

**ViewController2.swift**

```
    class ViewController2: UIViewController {

overload func viewDidLoad() {
        globalVariable = "some string data"
    }
}
```

you can now access that variable globally.

---

### Segue Option

I think a better way to handle sending data back and forth between View Controllers is by using delegates and the prepareForSegue function which is covered in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089152/sending-data-with-segue-with-swift).

You declare your prepareForSegue function like so:

**View Controller 1**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        var yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
        yourNextViewController.value = yourValue
```

**ViewController 2**

```
class yourNextViewControllerClass {

    var value:Int! // or whatever
```

The you can call it programmatically

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifierInStoryboard", sender: self)
```

If you want to set values back from your second View Controller, you can use a delegate Method, to respect the original author of this content I'll redirect you to his post:

[Read the rest from the original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089152/sending-data-with-segue-with-swift)

Comment: but will it be part of ViewController1 though ? Seems like it's outside the class and just that it's declared in the file. My real-world scenario is a UITableViewCell with some properties exposed that needs to be filled in in the willDisplayCell method.

Comment: It will be global making it available to your entire project. I'm working on an edit to my post with an additional option.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not a big fan of making it a global var. I think I'll end up having bunch of global vars if i go that route and honestly i think that property should be tied to that class. I've edited my first comment to say that in my project, i'm using it on a UITableViewCell so passing it in the segue is not an option (not using a storyboard). My current plan is to make a public function and pass all the params as a Model or a dictionary and let the UITableViewCell use that param to populate its cell. It seems strange that making a class public forces me to make all its functions to be publi

Comment: no problem, if you solve your problem post it back here as an answer, I'd like to see how you do it. Thanks!