# How to pass data to other views?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I need help to pass data of type boolean from checkboxes , from one view to the other , like in the image

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vy8t.jpg)

so if user select [True, True , True] should take the user to "Thats Good" viewController , Else "Too Bad" View Controller

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089152/sending-data-with-segue-with-swift/26089243#26089243

Answer (score 1):

You can send data using the prepareForSegue method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier") {
var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;

svc.toPass = textField.text

}
}
```

Here is a great video to get you started: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw)

Comment: thanks , ill try that c: