# Try to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but not called for first time

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a very strange question, that is when I called the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method for first time then it doesn't work.

If I called it again, it will be done. When I set a breakpoint at the first time, the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` also will perform but it will not push to next controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    ChatRoom *room = [_rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (!room.conv) {
        room.conv = [[_im imClient] conversationForId:room.convid];
    }
    CDChatRoomViewController* chatRoomVC=[[CDChatRoomViewController alloc] init];
    chatRoomVC.room = room;
    chatRoomVC.convId = room.convid;
    chatRoomVC.converSation = room.conv;
    chatRoomVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatRoomVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: check the method name properly

Comment: This problem only occurs on iPhone, when i use simulator to test it, everything is OK.

Comment: Can you please post some code!

Answer (score 0):

It is advise to check your method once, there are two methods which looks very identical to each other

//This Below method will get called when your cell is getting Selected

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//Cell selected
}
```

//This Below method will get called when your cell is getting deselected. This might be your case

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//Cell deselected

}
```

When you select a cell in tableview, tableview fire deselect method for selected cell (except multiple selection is On)

Hope this will justify answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure the method which i called is right.                                        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: we may able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

First you need to learn how to use segue to transfer data between view controller. It's pretty faster and good way to transfer the data between View Controller. There was other way too like Delegate.

At your current view controller, please declare this

```
var selectedCD : Int = 0
```

At your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, please fix these.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    yourTableName.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    // There is no need to do "tableView.allowsSelection = NO;"
    selectedCD = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToChatRoom", sender: self)
    // "goToChatRoom" is the name of segue which will go to CDChatRoomViewController which you need to set this at Storyboard.

}
```

At `ViewWillAppear()` of `CDChatRoomViewController`

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

Then create the following segue method at where you do UITableView Delegate method,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    if segue.identifier == "goToChatRoom"{
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! CDChatRoomViewController
        // handle selectedCD logic here
        ChatRoom *room = [_rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (!room.conv) {
            room.conv = [[_im imClient] conversationForId:room.convid];
        } 
        destinationController.room = room;
        destinationController.convId = room.convid;
        destinationController.converSation = room.conv;
    }
 }
```

Please edit some of your Objective-C code in my answer cause I really don't know what you are doing.

You can learn using segues here :

[Sending data with Segue with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089152/sending-data-with-segue-with-swift)

Try that way

> **Remember, don't add implementations [that need to do processing which use CPU or RAM] on didSelectRowAtIndexPath**.