# I'm writing iOS app in Swift. Should I use singletons?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, singleton, swift2

Let's say I'm creating a workout app and need to let the user to create new workouts and exercises.

We'll get the following view controllers:
Workouts -> New Workout -> Choose existing or Create new -> Create a new workout -> Choose exercises or Create new -> Create a new exercise -> Sets & Reps.

The user should be able to go back and forth between those views while creating a new workout. So the workout parameters should be saved somewhere temporary until the user is happy with everything and clicks "Save workout" button which finally saves it to sql database/coredata.

Should I be passing workout parameters between views using [segues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25215574/4833237) and [delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25523091/4833237) or should I create and use "NewWorkout" and "NewExercise" [singletons](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton) here?
Will singleton approach work fine if my user needs to create another workout? Can I just destroy the first instance and create a new one?

I've already started with segues and it's a mess. Want to refactor my code until it's not too late.

Comment: How about creating a temporary workout in core data and pass the workout id between controllers?

Comment: That's actually an option too. But I kind of like singleton more here. Since I don't want to end up with a garbage collector for unfinished workouts hanging in CoreData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the draft workout would be a good singleton. You could create a singleton for the management of all workouts. You could give that object a draftWorkout field. And a clearDraft and saveDraft methods.

Comment: That what I was thinking about, thanks. Anything bad I should avoid here not to step onto one of singleton anti-patterns?

Answer (score 0):

singletons - it's bad decision, normally you should crate some kind of "Workout" object on first step and move it through all the steps...