# swift: Refreshing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, refresh

I have 2 view controllers. Profile and SignIn. Actually Profile is root view controller. And When I press sign in button, signInViewController dismiss. How to update or refresh profileViewController after this?

I tried something like this:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "\(name)"

}
```

but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can user protocols to pass data between viewControllers, to do that you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522912/passing-data-back-from-view-controllers-xcode) question