# iOS 10 go back to root in nav stack with parameters

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, xcode8, ios10

I have an initial `ViewController` that is a `TableView` with lots of data. I have a title bar button item that links to another `TableView` with a summary of the data in the first `ViewController`. I currently have it so that when you click on a `cell`, it redirects the user back to the first `ViewController` and scrolls them to the proper `cells`. However, it adds the view to the stack and doesn't actually move them back properly. I think I would be able to do this through `Unwind` segues, but I can't seem to get them to work through cell clicks. Is there a better way that I can achieve this?

When I switch to the other view, I also need to set two variables in the initial controller to tell it what index to scroll to.

Comment: Where you added code to scroll , make sure to add such line in viewWillAppear not in viewDidLoad

Comment: Well the scrolling functionality already works, I just want the segue to make the view go back in the nav stack, not forward.

Comment: for this you can use self.navigationcontroller.popview method

Comment: Yeah that takes me back to the previous controller, but I still need to pass two variables to the controller

Comment: for this you can use delegate to pass value to previous controller , if that okey for you then i can provide you the code how to send variable to back viewcontroller through delgate pattern

Comment: Yeah I'll try it!

Comment: Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/3400991

Answer (score 0):

1.UNWind Segue :
suppose that we need to programmatically trigger the backward navigation, based on an interaction with something other than the default “back” button on the navigation bar. How would you do it? Yep – you’ve got it: by using an unwind segue.

2.Other way is usual : `PopViewController` Method

As per your question , you can go with option 2 which is more easy .

As far as Sending data from SecondViewController to FirstViewController you can use delegate pattern to send data back.
Here is few useful post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25523091/3400991

Feel free to comment. Thanks