# Dismiss the view controller which have navigation controller and pass the value back to main view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an `mainViewcontroller` in that one button called get value.Then i am calling `dataviewcontroller` to select any item in collection view cell.Once user select any cell.That particular `dataviewcontroller`  will dismiss and while dismiss it will have the user selected item name and it will display in `mainViewcontroller` .Now the view controller is not dismissing.

Here the code :

In my `mainViewcontroller`:

```
var SelectedName: String? = ""

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        currentTF.text = SelectedName

    }
```

Now `dataviewcontroller` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) != nil {

            selectedNamesss = allitems[indexPath.row] as String
        }

        calldismiss()
      print(selectedNamesss)

    }

func calldismiss() {


        if let presenter = presentingViewController as? mainViewcontroller {
            presenter.SelectedName = selectedNamesss
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Now how can i solve this.My viewcontroller is not dismising and values also not showing.

Thanks in advance ~

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion is to use "UnwindSegue" technique, which is simply works like "PerformSegue", So you can send back values very easily using prepare for segue and will be back to main controller. [Here is tutorial for unwind segue](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/). Or you can find more from google.

Answer (score 0):

For The problem where data is not showing, problem is with this condition:

```
if let presenter = presentingViewController as? mainViewcontroller {
            presenter.SelectedName = selectedNamesss
        }
```

this condition will never be true as the presentingViewController would always be a UINavigationController. so you need to change that may be something like follows:

```
if let presenter = (presentingViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers.first! as? mainViewcontroller {
            presenter.SelectedName = name
        }
```

Here i am using viewControllers.first! in condition as mainViewcontroller was at first index of the viewControllers array. Check the viewControllers array and find the index of mainViewcontroller and make changes accordingly.

I made this changes and the code is working for me. I am getting the selected name on the mainViewcontroller.

Also i would like to mention that this is not the right way to transfer data backwards. You can use delegates, blocks or unwind segue to achieve this.

Though this is working i am attaching a gif to show this working.

[image]

Regarding the issue where your controller is not being dismissed, i am presenting the controller in following way:

```
let dataVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataviewcontroller") as! dataviewcontroller
 self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Try this and see if this helps you :)

Comment: the is this line is correct ` dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: yes it is correct i am dismissing it with this same code

Comment: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashBoard", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewVC")   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)`

Comment: I am doing push navigation...bez i have used some images in navigation bar of my data viewcontroller

Comment: Ohh man you are pushing the view controller then how it will dismiss? I have updated my answer on how I have presented the controller. To present controller use

self.navigationController?.present(destinationVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: If you are pushing the controller then instead of  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) user self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: But now i am using view controller with push...is there any ides or solution to `pop the vc` or to pass the value to my `mainvc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157670/discussion-between-ios-mib-and-david).