# pass value through another vc solution

Tags: ios, swift

I pretty doubt that what is different between value by using prepare func

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MainToTimer") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! YourViewController
        vc.var_name = "Your Data"
    }
}
```

or declare global variable  for example

in VC1

```
var justsimpleint:Int! = 0 //out side class

viewdidload(){
 justsimpleint = justsimpleint + 2
}
```

in VC2

```
viewdidload(){
print(justsimpleint)   // it will be 2
}
```

Comment: Refere here, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S this is a *Swift* documentation link, it has nothing to do with working with iOS, passing data between view controllers.

Comment: What is the question? A simple google search "Passing data between view controllers" will yield plenty of results.  see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AhmadF , View controllers are classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using global variables to pass data between VCs is not a good idea. Global variables are things that should be used carefully. If you want to pass data from a View Controller A to View Controller B, which A presents, do it in the `prepareForSegue` method. If you want to pass data from View Controller B to View Controller A, which presents B, use the delegate pattern.

Global variables are bad for this purpose because:

- They can be accessed from anywhere. This makes it easy for you to change them accidentally.
- It is easier to spot errors. Say you have a global variable `val` that VC A and B will use. You pass some data from A to B. The first time A presented B, the data was passed successfully. The second time, the data was not sent due to some error in your logic. This would mean that B will receive the data you sent last time and everything will seem OK from the outside. If you pass the data in `prepareForSegue`, VC B will not get the data if no data was passed. A likely `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional` error will occur. This makes it easy for you to tell what went wrong.
- Global variables will hold references to objects, even when the VC that needs it is deallocated. This means that there will be some useless objects floating around in memory after the VC is dismissed if you don't clean it properly.

Answer (score 1):

By default, assuming that you are working with storyboards, you should use the [*segues*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) for passing data to the next view controller.

Global variable would be useful in case of you want it to be *shared* in the whole application, you could create a [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID177) class for setting global properties.

Also, for passing back between view controllers, you could create a *delegate* to achieve it, you might want to check [Passing data back from view controllers Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522912/passing-data-back-from-view-controllers-xcode).

<sub>If you are unfamiliar with work with delegates, you might also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift/40503024#40503024).</sub>

Comment: ty for explain this